# Determining posterior distribution of θ given the prior p.d.f.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Second post here, hope I can get some help.
This

Suppose that there is a proportion θ of defects in a manufacture lot that is unknown, and the prior pdf for θ is:

f(θ) = 2(1-θ) for 0 < θ < 1,
       0  otherwise.

Suppose that in a random sample of eight items exactly three are found to be defective. Determine the posterior distribution of θ.

What I have:
I ended up with a beta distribution with alpha = 4, and beta = 6.
However my book's answer is this:
Beta distribution with parameters α = 4 and β = 7.

Can someone explain to me why beta is 7?  A step by step solution would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra "1" in the $\beta$ term comes from the factor $1-\theta$ in $f$.

Prior: $f(\theta)=2(1-\theta)$.

Likelihood: $\binom{8}{3}\theta^3 (1-\theta)^5$.

$\text{Posterior} \propto \text{likelihood}\times \text{prior} \propto \theta^{4-1}(1-\theta)^{7-1}$

Comment: Ah, so it is likelihood × prior?  I think I did likelihood ∝ prior, so I did not account for the other (1-θ), it seems like.

Comment: I made a small typo that I have fixed, but yes, posterior is proportional to likelihood times prior. [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help!

I am also even more in the dark on another problem, perhaps I could get some assistance also:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803438/probability-given-x-y-are-independent-rand-variables-and-2-p-d-f-s