# X,Y~N(0,1), P(0<X<Y)?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the two independent and identically distributed standard normal random variables $X,Y∼N(0,1)$. What is the probability: $P(0<X<Y)$?

Intuitively, I would think the answer is $1/8$, because $X$ has $1/2$ chance of being positive and, if positive, would have an expected value at the $75th$ percentile of the standard normal curve. $Y$ would then have $1/4$ chance of being greater than $X$. $1/2*1/4 = 1/8$

I guess otherwise I can set up integrals and change to polar coordinates to solve? A bit confused...

Comment: You might find this useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261073/finding-probability-pxy

Comment: Hint: By symmetry, $P(0 < X < Y) = P(0 < Y < X)$.  And these two events are disjoint - what do you get if you add these probabilities?

Comment: Thanks guys. @NateEldredge, I assume that adding the probabilities would equal 1/4, because both X and Y would have to be positive with 1/2 probability each. Right?